# R: How to split a dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

My data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pvxvM6ydI58kvcjyKJT_vI0ElNWlmJcGe4l-1lD4XqA/edit?usp=sharing

I have a big dataframe which I've subset to reduce the number of columns

`genesABDF <- select(genes, Species, Class, BfrA, BfrB, Bfd, Ftn)`

then managed to split using `split()`:

`ABDFclass <- split(genesABDF, genesABDF$Class)`

This gave me some lists(?) which I've converted back into dataframes

`alpha <- data.frame(ABDFclass$Alphaproteobacteria)`

Then for each of my classes (Alphaproteobacteria, Betaproteobacteria, Bacteroidetes, Deltaproteobacteria, Enterobacteria, Firmicutes, Gammaproteobacteria) I want to filter the data to see which combinations the proteins appear in from the options: A, BD, Ftn, ABD, AFtn, BDFtn, ABDFtn.

This method works perfectly fine but I'd really like some help with how to turn it into a loop because I want to repeat this for my other classes.

```
alphaA <- filter(alpha, BfrA==1 & BfrB==0 & Bfd==0 & Ftn==0)
alphaBD <- filter(alpha, BfrA==0 & BfrB==1 & Bfd==1 & Ftn==0)
alphaFtn <- filter(alpha, BfrA==0 & BfrB==0 & Bfd==0 & Ftn==1)
alphaABD <- filter(alpha, BfrA==1 & BfrB==1 & Bfd==1 & Ftn==0)
alphaAFtn <- filter(alpha, BfrA==1 & BfrB==0 & Bfd==0 & Ftn==1)
alphaBDFtn <- filter(alpha, BfrA==0 & BfrB==1 & Bfd==1 & Ftn==1)
alphaABDFtn <- filter(alpha, BfrA==1 & BfrB==1 & Bfd==1 & Ftn==1)
```

EDIT:
`dput(head(genesABDF,25))`

````
"Mycolicibacterium smegmatis", "Streptomyces lydicus", "Agrobacterium fabrum", 
"Azospirillum brasilense", "Blastochloris viridis", "Brucella abortus", 
"Cereibacter sphaeroides", "Gluconobacter thailandicus", "Magnetospirillum gryphiswaldense", 
"Magnetospirillum magnetotacticum", "Reyranella sp.", "Rhizobium borbori", 
"Rhodospirillaceae bacterium", "Rhodospirillum rubrum", "Alistipes finegoldii", 
"Flavobacterium psychrophilum", "Mangrovimonas yunxiaonensis", 
"Maribacter polysiphoniae", "Achromobacter insuavis", "Acidovorax cattleyae", 
"Acidovorax valerianellae", "Alcaligenes ammonioxydans", "Alcaligenes aquatilis"
), Class = c("Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", "Bacteroidetes", "Bacteroidetes", 
"Bacteroidetes", "Betaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", 
"Betaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria"
), BfrA = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), BfrB = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), Bfd = c(0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0), Ftn = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: Try to share data (or a sample of them) with `dput()` and printing your output. Sometimes it's not nice to downloand something from a complete stranger.

Comment: @s__ I've tried to, is that how you meant?

Comment: you have to write in your R `dput(head(genesABDF,20))`  and paste the output **editing** your question (the output is going to be someting `structure(...` ): that piece of code is going to print in a shareable way the first 20 rows of your dataset. Note `20` is a random paramenter, you have to choose a good amount of rows to make sense in your question.